# Animation data override?

Tags: animation

I'm relatively new to Blender, and I'm creating an animation. I'm using some MoCap software to create animated rigs to then add to models for the animation.

My issue is I don't know how to add animation data after the previous animation is over.

In the gif I added, I want the model to finish the animation from one rig and continue with the other. Is there a way where I don't have override the previous animation data?

[Gif of that I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KaYm.jpg)

Comment: do you need to use 2 different armatures? couldn't you use the NLA so that the second animation arrives after the first one?

Comment: they are the same armatures, how would I use the NLA? im not quite sure what that is im still pretty new to blender lol. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ill do some research into NLA. do you have any other suggestions as to how I can fix this issue? thanks again

Comment: Yep NLA was the right way to go! thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is push down your actions in the *NLA* windows and make the second action follow the first one. Maybe follow some tutorials on *NLA* because you may be a bit lost at the beginning, for example keep in mind that if you have an action playing in the *Dope Sheet* it will override the *NLA* actions.