# NLA Animation Model location Jump Help

Tags: animation

I previously asked a question about merging two rig animations onto one rig (using NLA) [Link to previous discussion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186044/animation-data-override-help/186051#186051)
I now have a question as to how I can track the motion of the previous animation so the next animation starts where the previous one ends, i.e. as seen in the provided gif, the new animation location moves the entire model, where I would like the model to transition to the next animation, keeping its location.. if that makes since... Thanks again in advance!

[link to gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4wE6.jpg)

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: woops sorry about that lol

Comment: at the beginning of action#2, in Pose mode, you could move the root bone (if you have one) so that the pose location match the pose location of the end of action#1? Not sure you have a root bone though...

Comment: gotcha....  i initially had the pelvis bone as the root bone, but It appears that because of the motion capture software, there are key frames for every frame for each bone, and editing the root bone messes with the overall model... I believe I need to go in and add a master root bone as you will... Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: you could also select all the bones in Pose mode, open the Graph Editor, search for Z Location to only display the location curves, and move everything in order to match with the Z location at the end of action#1, then X Location, etc...

Comment: Imma give that a try! thanks!